# Is the angularfire2 library deprecated?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

After creating a new Angular (my Angular version: 6.14.10) project in the console `"ng new 'project name'"`, then installing these libraries with npm: `“firebase@4.2.0”` and `“angularfire2@4.0.0-rc-1”` (They are old because I'm following an old Angular course)
Editing the app.module.ts file as he does in the video:

```
import { environment } from “./…/environments/environment”;

import { BrowserModule } from “@angular/platform-browser”;

import { NgModule } from “@angular/core”;

import { AppRoutingModule } from “./app-routing.module”;

import { AppComponent } from “./app.component”;

import { AngularFireModule } from “angularfire2”;

import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from “angularfire2/database”;

import { AngularFireAuthModule } from “angularfire2/auth”;

@NgModule({

declarations: [AppComponent],

imports: [

BrowserModule,

AppRoutingModule,

AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

AngularFireDatabaseModule,

AngularFireAuthModule, ],

providers: [],

bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})

export class AppModule {}
```

and finally, doing “ng serve” in the project directory, I got these 2 errors:

> Warning: Entry point ‘angularfire2’ contains deep imports into
> ‘C:/Users/elida/OneDrive/organic shop app/node_modules/firebase/app’.
> This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry
> points to be out of order.
>
> Error: The target entry-point “angularfire2” has missing dependencies:
>
> @angular/core rxjs/Observable

And the page does not work in the browser, it gives a 404 error.

The author of the course did it 4 years ago, I don’t know what have changed with these angular libraries, how it is done now?
Is the angularfire2 deprecated, and if so, what to install with npm and what to do in the app.module.ts file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have imported in old way. Try to import like this.
For ex.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

It worked for me, let me know if this works for you as well.

Comment: Should I install new dependencies when doing these new imports? If I just overwrite them, the compiler complains saying that it cannot find its module

Comment: Yup, uninstall current firebase version and reinstall with `firebase@7.24.0`

Comment: What exactly do I need to install instead of “firebase@4.2.0” and “angularfire2@4.0.0-rc-1”?

Comment: Run `npm install firebase@7.24.0` to install firebase version and run `npm install angularfire2@5.4.2` to install angularfire.

Comment: Did it help?? @EM

Comment: I started with a new ng project, and instead of installing angularfire2, I installed @angular/fire, then I imported like so in the app.module: 
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire 
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

Comment: That solved the initial problem, but the differences in implementation between the deprecated libraries and the new ones throughout the course have made it non-viable, for me.

Comment: Yup, that will happen with change of version but you'll get all functionalities on video tutorials and documentation with a slight change in your already existing code. Your question was about importing angularfire dependencies and I answered that. You can raise other questions and experts here will answer them. I think our threads are heading towards closure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to StackOverflow. Your answer could use a little more context or an explanation to what your suggested command actually does. Could you review your answer?